# How to create letter with related data?

Tags: email, email-template, pdf, joined-reports, csv

I want to create a letter that can be sent via email or saved as PDF (or in the worst case exported as csv).
The data for the letter comes from the following related objects:

[image]

The important object is `Session`. You enter the sessions the `Partner` has, with `Date` from ... to (one day would mean entering the same date twice) and `Topic`. `Topic` has a dropdown with three topics `z1`, `z2`, `z3`. There will be many `Session` items for one `Partner`.

I want to create a letter that displays the `Consultant` and his `Principal` in the header, the `Partner` in the subject and the details of all related `Session` entries as conten. The letter should hence look like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot create this via a joined-report, as I will always get all related information in one long line.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Using email template of type  Visualforce template may match for your requirement.Are you familiar with visualforce coding?

Comment: http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2012/11/sending-document-as-attachment-in-form.html                                                  i had blogged also on related requirement like this .May be you may like to look at code and tweak as per your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with a workaround using Microsoft Word's mail merge:

- Export the data as .xls
- Use Word's Mail Merge with Catalog / Category (see this topic at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/527466/184195)) to sort the data by category